# Return custom error message to login entry point with eventListeners

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

In a rest API, i implemented 2 event listners to handle Authentication success and failure. It works fine and I do have a 403 error but i want to return a JSON Message.

For my login I implemented, the following :

```
@PostMapping("/login")
public ResponseEntity<UserResponse> loadUserByUsername(@RequestBody UserDetailsRequestModel userDetails) {
    if(userDetails.getEmail().isEmpty() || userDetails.getPassword().isEmpty()) {
        throw new UserServiceException(ErrorMessages.MISSING_REQUIRED_FIELD.getErrorMessage());
    }
    authenticate(userDetails.getEmail(), userDetails.getPassword());
    UserResponse userRestResponseModel = new UserResponse();

    ModelMapper modelMapper = new CustomMapper();
    modelMapper.getConfiguration().setMatchingStrategy(MatchingStrategies.STANDARD);

    UserDto loggedInUser = userService.getUser(userDetails.getEmail());

    userRestResponseModel = modelMapper.map(loggedInUser, UserResponse.class);
    // retrieve authorities manually
    for(RoleDto roleDto: loggedInUser.getRoles()) {
        Collection<AuthorityDto> authorityDtos = authorityService.getRoleAuthorities(roleDto);
        roleDto.setAuthorities(authorityDtos);
    }
    UserPrincipalManager userPrincipal = new UserPrincipalManager(modelMapper.map(loggedInUser, UserEntity.class));

    // authorities are not fetched ... so we'll fetch them manually
    HttpHeaders jwtHeader = getJwtHeader(userPrincipal);

    ResponseEntity<UserResponse> returnValue =
            new ResponseEntity<>(userRestResponseModel, jwtHeader, HttpStatus.OK);

    return returnValue;
}


private void authenticate(String userName, String password) {
    AuthenticationManager authenticationManager =
            (AuthenticationManager) SpringApplicationContext.getBean("authenticationManager");
    authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userName, password));
}
private HttpHeaders getJwtHeader(UserPrincipalManager userPrincipal) {
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    String token = jwtTokenProvider.generateJwtToken(userPrincipal);
    headers.add(SecurityConstants.TOKEN_PREFIX, token);
    return headers;
}


@Component
public class AuthenticationFailureListener {
    private final LoginAttemptService loginAttemptService;


    @Autowired
    public AuthenticationFailureListener(LoginAttemptService loginAttemptService) {
        this.loginAttemptService = loginAttemptService;
    }

    @EventListener
    public void onAuthenticationFailure(AuthenticationFailureBadCredentialsEvent event) throws ExecutionException {
        Object principal = event.getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
        if (principal instanceof String) {
            String username = (String) event.getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
            loginAttemptService.addUserToLoginAttemptCache(username);
        }
    }
}
```

In my loginAttemptService I try to prepare a return to a rest response.

```
@Override
public void addUserToLoginAttemptCache(String username) {
    int attempts = 0;
    try {
        attempts = SecurityConstants.AUTH_ATTEMPT_INCREMENT + loginAttemptCache.get(username);
        loginAttemptCache.put(username, attempts);
        String message = "";
        if(!errorContext.isHasExceededMaxAttempts()) {
            message = "Invalid email or password. You tried : " + attempts + "/" + SecurityConstants.MAX_AUTH_ATTEMPTS;
        } else {
            message = "You reached " + attempts + " attempts. Account is now locked for " + SecurityConstants.LOCK_DURATION + " min";
        }
        throw new SecurityServiceException(message);
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

My issue is the following: using ControllerAdvice won't work because the error is handled before it could reach it. How can I then return a JSON response to the client ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did find a trick for this issue. I created a ManagedBean class

```
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor @NoArgsConstructor
@ManagedBean @ApplicationScope
public class ServletContext {
    private HttpServletRequest request;
    private HttpServletResponse response;
}
```

I inject it in my AuthenticationFilter custom class. Here in my attemptAuthentication method I can get access to HttpServletRequest and HttpServletResponse objects. I just have to set my ServletContext object with the request and the response.

```
@Override
public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request,
                                            HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException {
    // we may need to pass request and response object if we fail authentication,
    servletContext.setRequest(request);
    servletContext.setResponse(response);

    // spring tries to authenticate user
    try {
        UserLoginRequestModel creds = new ObjectMapper()
                .readValue(request.getInputStream(), UserLoginRequestModel.class);

        // we return authentication with email and password
        return authenticationManager.authenticate(
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        creds.getEmail(),
                        creds.getPassword(),
                        new ArrayList<>()
                )
        );
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Now in my AuthenticationFailureListener, I also inject my ServletContext class and retrieve the values in the method that handle onAuthenticationFailure:

```
@EventListener
public void onAuthenticationFailure(AuthenticationFailureBadCredentialsEvent event) throws ExecutionException, IOException {
    System.out.println(event);
    Object principal = event.getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
    if (principal instanceof String) {
        String username = (String) event.getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
        loginAttemptService.addUserToLoginAttemptCache(username);
        int attempts = loginAttemptService.getLoginAttempts(username);
        String message;
        if(!loginAttemptService.hasExceededMaxAttempts(username)) {
            message = "Invalid email or password. You tried : " + attempts + "/" + SecurityConstants.MAX_AUTH_ATTEMPTS;
        } else {
            message = "You reached " + attempts + " attempts. Account is now locked for " + SecurityConstants.LOCK_DURATION + " min";
        }
        ErrorMessageResponse errorMessageResponse = new ErrorMessageResponse(new Date(), message);
        HttpServletResponse response = servletContext.getResponse();
        response.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
        new ObjectMapper().writeValue(response.getOutputStream(), errorMessageResponse);
    }
}
```

At this stage, I do have HttpServletResponse object and I can use it to write value. I do believe there may be more elegant ways to handle this, but it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.accessDeniedHandler` at your `HttpSecurity` in you Security Config.

Below Simple way de return JSON For 403 error :

1. Define a private method in Config Security like this :

> ```
> @Configuration
> @EnableWebSecurity
> public class SecurityConfig  extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
>
> .....
>
> private void writeResponse(HttpServletResponse httpResponse, int code, String message) throws IOException {
>         httpResponse.setContentType("application/json");
>         httpResponse.setStatus(code);
>         httpResponse.getOutputStream().write(("{\"code\":" + code + ",").getBytes());
>         httpResponse.getOutputStream().write(("\"message\":\"" + message + "\"}").getBytes());
>         httpResponse.getOutputStream().flush();
>     }
>
> }
> ```

2. Add exceptionHandling at your HttpSecurity Config :

> ```
> @Override
> protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
> ....
> http  = http.exceptionHandling()
>                 .accessDeniedHandler((request, response, accessDeniedException) -> {
>                             this.writeResponse(response,HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN,accessDeniedException.getMessage());
>                         }
>                         )
>                 .and();
>
> ....
>
> }
> ```

Comment: I tried this in another similar project and it doesn't seem to work. I'm going to find out how to implement this stuff. it seems rather nice to do. I will have a look at Baledung here: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-exceptions